# Characterization of direct product of rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

[Characterization of the direct product of rings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZBFuj.png)

I'm trying to understand the given characterization of direct products of rings. 
More specifically, I realize that given a direct product the statement holds, but how exactly does it **characterize** the direct product?

Comment: The given property is a "*universality property*", it characterizes / determines / singles out *up to isomorphism* any = the one and only object with the given property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is any other ring $S$ satisfying the characterization, then $S$ is isomorphic to $\prod_{i=1}^n R_i$ via unique isomorphism. The [proof](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Product_(Category_Theory)_is_Unique) is standard and works for any category where direct products exist.

These kind of characterizations are usually called [universal properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_property).

Comment: Just to see if i understand this correctly: If i take a ring $A$ (Does it have to be a ring of n-tuples then, so as to ble able to define $\pi_i : A \rightarrow R_i$ ?) with the property that given any ring $R$ with homomorphisms $\phi_i : R \rightarrow R_i $  $(i=1,...,n)$, there exists a unique homomorphism $\phi: R \rightarrow A$ for which $\pi_i \circ \phi = \phi_i$, then $A$ is isomorphic with the direct product of the $R_i$'s?

Can i demonstrate this by looking at the case where $R=\prod_{i=1}^n R_i$ and defining the homomorphisms $R \rightarrow R_i $ to be $\phi_i = \pi_i$?

Comment: In principle it doesn't have to be a ring of $n$-tuples, though it turns out to be isomorphic to a ring like that. The "projections" $\pi_i:A\to R_i$ shouldn't be assumed to take any explicit form before you know the isomorphism. 

You got it right, that's explicitly the characterization by universal property. Yes, you can do that, you will prove that any "product" is cannonically isomorphic to the usual product. You can also choose $A=\prod_{i=1}^n R_i$ instead, and the proof will be rather symmetric, since it is enough to know that both $A$ and $R$ satisfy the same property.

Answer (score 0):

It characterizes the direct product in the sense that every other ring with that property is isomorphic to the direct product.

That is, the direct product has a [universal property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_property) that makes it unique (up to isomorphism.)